# Problem with viewing normal DataFrame in python, looks like string

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a csv data, when I open through the pd.read_csv, it looks like the following table. I have never seen a DataFrame like this, how can I see the normal DataFrame?

```
    column name;description
0   article_id;unique article identifier
1   product_tier;premium status of the article
2   make_name;name of the car manufacturer
3   price;price of the article
4   first_zip_digit;first digit of the zip code of...
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to reproduce existing tutorials and documentation. Did you try looking at the original file? Did you notice how it was formatted? Can you observe a pattern to what is wrong in the result that you get? For example, do you know what the column headings are supposed to be? Do you see a simple relationship between what the headings are supposed to be, and what you're supposed to get? Does that suggest to you a simple way to describe what `read_csv` is doing wrong? Now, *what happened when you read the documentation*, and looked for something to address that problem?

Comment: (Another hint: what does CSV stand for? What is the `;` symbol called? Do you see how this doesn't quite match up? Again, read the documentation to see how to account for that.)

Comment: Thanks I understand ! but don't give me a negative mark !

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted your question, but please understand that downvoting [is a content rating system, not something that people are doing to criticize or attack you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just pass `sep` parameter in `pd.read_csv()` and set that equal to `';'`:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv',sep=';')
```

**Note:** The default seperator for `pd.read_csv()` method is `','` as your csv file is seperated by `';'` so you have to pass `sep` parameter explicitly in `read_csv()` method and set that equal to `';'`